# Prevent pixel decimals when using transform scale

Tags: javascript, css, css-transforms

I have a slider which consists of iframes that are 1366px x 768px which I scale to fit on window resize. However, when 1366 is divided I can randomly get decimals on the actual width of the element which causes what I call as 'pixel breaking'.

Notice the while line on the second image. This is actually the second slide which is my problem. Example; 1366px becomes 1045.234234px so they don't line up properly.

I know I can also add a width by removing the decimals as `parseInt(scaleAmount * 1366)` but I don't think that can always be accurate with different resolutions.

Anything I can try to resolve or minimise this?

[image: Non-scaled version]

[image: scaled]

```
var $el = $(element);
var elHeight = 768;
var elWidth = 1366;
var $wrapper = $(parent);

function doResize(event, ui) {
    var scale, origin;

    scale = Math.min(
        ui.size.width / elWidth,
        ui.size.height / elHeight
    );

    $el.css({
        'transform': "scale(" + scale + ")",
        '-webkit-transform': "scale(" + scale + ")"
    });
}
```

Comment: Could you provide us a jsFiddle to have a deeper look at your problem ?

Comment: @AntoineGautrain sure. You literally have to make the viewport really small so you can see the pixels breaking. Play around with the height of the result window. The blue line on the second slide is very obvious. https://jsfiddle.net/sadikyalcin/t0a31mpf/18/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I think I've resolved it. I convert the transform scale to pixel value. Round up the pixel. And finally, convert the rounded pixel back to a transform scale. So the scaled pixel will always be an even number so therefore the pixels would not break anymore.

```
scale = Math.min(
    ui.size.width / elWidth,
    ui.size.height / elHeight
);

var scaleInPixels = scale * elWidth;
var evenPixel = 2 * Math.round(scaleInPixels / 2);
var finalScale = evenPixel / elWidth;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're converting to a string, you can just trim off the decimal part of the number using `scale.toFixed(0)`.

Comment: I can indeed but that is not 100% accurate. I'm trying to fit the slider 100% in height or width. If I trim the decimals I can get an odd pixel or two.