# CSS Borders, Unwanted Gaps and Sub-Pixel Rendering Issues

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm designing a blog post preview tile for my personal website. Whatever I try to do, there is always a gap between the image and its own bottom border, or a gap between the image and the border of the container. It appears on mobile, when zooming, and when scaling. It's a really simple design and I'm going crazy and can't figure out how to get it to work. I know it's related to sub pixel rendering issues. Please help me! I would either like the gap gone or to render as the same color as the border so it doesn't look jank.

```css
body {
    background: rgba(255, 225, 172, 1);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: [row-start] 1fr [row-end row2-start] 6fr [row2-end row3-start] 1fr [row3-end];
    grid-template-columns: [col-start] 1fr [col-end];
    row-gap: 60px;
    padding-left: 120px;
    padding-right: 120px;
}

.blog_preview_container {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1;
    height: 354px !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.blog_preview_titlecard {
    height: 352px;
    width: 272px;
}

.blog_tile {
    height: 340px !important;
    width: 240px !important;
    margin: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 6px solid black;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    color: white;
    display: inline;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.blog_tile:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

.blog_tile_image {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 6px solid black;
}

.blog_tile_text {
    height: 138px;
    font-family: 'nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="blog_preview_container">
    <img class="blog_preview_titlecard" src="https://example.com/titlecard_location">
    <div class="blog_tile">
      <img class="blog_tile_image" src="https://example.com/img_location">
      <p class="blog_tile_text">Text Goes Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi! maybe it's not enough good answer but it's working for me can you try to set background-color: #000;  for ".blog_tile"

Answer (score 3):

I play with this image and it seems like you can just change the background-color of your blog_tile as black will remedy it.

```css
body {
    background: rgba(255, 225, 172, 1);
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: [row-start] 1fr [row-end row2-start] 6fr [row2-end row3-start] 1fr [row3-end];
    grid-template-columns: [col-start] 1fr [col-end];
    row-gap: 60px;
    padding-left: 120px;
    padding-right: 120px;
}

.blog_preview_container {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1;
    height: 354px !important;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.blog_preview_titlecard {
    height: 352px;
    width: 272px;
}

.blog_tile {
    height: 340px !important;
    width: 240px !important;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 6px solid black;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    color: white;
    background-color: white;

}

.blog_tile:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-color: black;
}

.blog_tile img {    
    height: 340px;
    width: 242px;
    object-fit: cover;
    margin: -1px 0px 0px -1px;
    
    }

.blog_tile_image {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 6px solid black;
}

.blog_tile_text {
    height: 138px;
    font-family: 'nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="blog_preview_container">
    <img class="blog_preview_titlecard" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/picturesque-morning-in-plitvice-national-park-colorful-spring-scene-picture-id1093110112?k=20&m=1093110112&s=612x612&w=0&h=3OhKOpvzOSJgwThQmGhshfOnZTvMExZX2R91jNNStBY=">
    <div class="blog_tile">
      <img class="blog_tile_image" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/picturesque-morning-in-plitvice-national-park-colorful-spring-scene-picture-id1093110112?k=20&m=1093110112&s=612x612&w=0&h=3OhKOpvzOSJgwThQmGhshfOnZTvMExZX2R91jNNStBY=">
      <p class="blog_tile_text">Text Goes Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: that is good work around but i didn't find any way to avoid this whiteout any workaround

Comment: I can look at it more. to see if there's more we can do about it.

Comment: @rootShiv seems like you can work around it by assigning the height and width of the image and make it object fit cover will do it also putting negative margin inside of the div will work see if that will work for you.

Comment: The background color is chosen using a script that randomly picks it from an array of the theme colors. I just have white there as a placeholder.

Comment: @rootShiv I guess I could set the background of the tile to match the border and then set the background of the text instead of the whole tile and that could avoid it.

Comment: @Crystal I played around with negative margins and couldn't get the desired result, but I'll try the contain.

Comment: I also forgot to mention for my code example, the images are autocropped to half the height of the block -6px for the bottom border. So it should be W240xH164.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a stripped down example that doesn't involve hard-coding any colors. It uses an absolutely positioned psuedo-element with a border that is overlaid above the image. The container is given a padding amount that is 1px smaller than the border width so it is rendered underneath it. The bottom border of the <img> is then relocated to the top of the <p> below it and the image is given a bottom margin of -1px.

```css
*, *::after, *::before { box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  background: rgba(255, 225, 172, 1);
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.blog_tile {
  position: relative;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: max-content 1fr;
  height: 340px;
  width: 240px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.blog_tile::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  border: 6px solid black;
}

.blog_tile:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}

.blog_tile img {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  object-fit: cover;
  line-height: 0;
  white-space: collapse;
}

.blog_tile p {
  margin: 0; padding: 3px;
  border-top: 6px solid black;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="blog_tile">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300">
  <p> TESTING </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh, I hadn't considered a pseudo element solution. Thanks for the help! Although I do see the divider pseudo element over extend the border on the right side by 1px depending on scale.

Comment: That's a shame, I hadn't noticed that problem. I don't think there's much you can do about that besides fine-tuning your scale amount to avoid it. [Here's a method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55304746/6036546) I found that uses javascript to round off the scale, maybe it will be of some use.

Comment: I was able to create a solution that did exactly as I wanted, see my post. Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

Try this may be it will help.

```
img {
    object-fit: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by having the tile background color match the border color, and then setting the background of the text with my script instead of background color of the tile. That way when gaps are created it matches the border color and doesn't look weird. Now it looks correct at all scales. it doesn't handle non-cropped images but all the images pulled are autocropped to the correct size in my PHP.

```js
window.onload = () => {
        var colors = ['#ffffff', '#ffbd4b', '#ff634b', '#4b9fff'];
        var nowhitecolors = ['#ffbd4b', '#ff634b', '#4b9fff'];
        document.querySelectorAll('.blog_tile').forEach(
            el => {
                        var randcolor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
                        el.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffff';
                        el.children[1].style.backgroundColor = randcolor;
                        if (randcolor ==='#ffffff') {
                                var randnowhitecolors = nowhitecolors[Math.floor(Math.random() * nowhitecolors.length)];
                                el.style.borderColor = randnowhitecolors;
                                el.children[0].style.borderColor = randnowhitecolors;
                                el.style.backgroundColor =randnowhitecolors;
                                el.style.color = randnowhitecolors;
                        };
                }
        );

};
```

```css
.blog_preview_container {
    grid-row: 2;
    grid-column: 1;
    height: 354px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    column-gap: 40px;
    row-gap: 40px;
}

.blog_tile {
    height: 340px;
    width: 240px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-width: 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 4px 4px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    color: white;
    display: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.blog_tile:hover {
    transform: scale(1.04);
}

.blog_tile img {
    height: 164px;
    width: 240px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-bottom-width: 6px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.blog_tile p {
    height: 138px;
    font-family: 'nunito', sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 900;
    line-height: 22px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 16px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="blog_preview_container">
    <div class="blog_tile">
      <img class="blog_tile_image" src="https://example.com/img_location">
      <p class="blog_tile_text">Text Goes Here</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Looks great at all screen sizes, no more gaps!